# Rails The Movie Database Gem sort by popularity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/aarongough/ruby-tmdb).

I know how to find a particular movie and get its information. But how do I list the 100 most popular movies? I don't see anything about popularity.

Comment: http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#get-%2F3%2Fmovie%2Fpopular

Comment: When investigating a gem's api that isn't documented, read the tests. They can provide important usage examples. See here: https://github.com/aarongough/ruby-tmdb/blob/master/test/unit/tmdb_movie_test.rb#L117. See here for TheMovieDatabase API call you want to run: http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#get-%2F3%2Fmovie%2Fpopular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library you are using looks out of date.

I would recommend either [ruby-tmdb](https://github.com/Irio/ruby-tmdb) which is a fork of the one you have referenced or [themoviedb](https://github.com/ahmetabdi/themoviedb).

With the last one you can just call [`Tmdb::Movie.popular`](https://github.com/ahmetabdi/themoviedb#movie) to get the latest popular films.

Comment: Ok, so I'm using themoviedb gem now. When i call Tmdb::Movie.popular I get 20 items in my view. But this doesn't work:

`<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  <%= movie.title %>
<% end %>`

It says 'title' is an undefined method.

Comment: Got it to work! I had to use `movie['title']` in stead of `movie.title` Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @user2255273 In case it helps, I would highly recommend using [PRY](http://pryrepl.org/) when learning a new library. For example you can run ls on an object to investigate what methods it has. I find this to be a highly intuitive way to work out how something has been designed.

Comment: Just a FYI: In the new version you can just call .title